# How do you upgrade version of pip on Repl.it?

Tags: pip, replit

I'm having issues upgrading pip using the pip3 install --upgrade pip3 command on Repl.it and getting this error:

```
Repl.it: Installing fresh packages

Usage: pip3 [options]

pip3: error: no such option: --upgrade

You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 19.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.


Repl.it: package installation failed!
```

How can I upgrade pip on Repl.it?

Comment: did you try running `pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: Yes I did, same error